# How do I incorporate Text to Speech into python script

Tags: python, email, twitter, text-to-speech

I'm trying to code my pi to speak my twitter hashtags and email. How and what would I use to incorporate TTS to my python script.

```
import tweepy
import time
import imaplib
import email

consumer_key = 'xxxxxx'

consumer_secret = 'xxxxx'

access_token = 'xxxxxx'

access_token_secret = 'xxxxxx'

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')

mail.login('xxxxx', 'xxxxx')

mail.select('inbox')


obj, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)


class Listener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):

    print('----------------')

    print(status.text)

for hashtag in status.entities['hashtags']:

    print("")

    return True


#error code



def on_error(self, status_code):

   print('Error with code: ' + str(status_code))

   return True



def on_timeout(self):

   print('timeout')

   return true



listener = Listener()
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, listener)


stream.filter(track=['#123Emergency'])


for num in data [0].split():

    type, data = mail.fetch(num, "(UID BODY[1])")

    msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])

    print 'Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0] [1])
```

So so far I have this and I need to incorporate TTS to this scripts. How would I get started?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. What have you tried so far? Please read the help section on how to post questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can make python speak using the pyttsx Python library.

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.setProperty('rate', 70)

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
for voice in voices:
print "Using voice:", repr(voice)
engine.setProperty('voice', voice.id)
engine.say("Hi there, how's you ?")
engine.say("A B C D E F G H I J K L M")
engine.say("N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z")
engine.say("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9")
engine.say("Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday")
engine.say("Violet Indigo Blue Green Yellow Orange Red")
engine.say("Apple Banana Cherry Date Guava")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: Sorry for the newbie questions, but how would I integrate this?

Comment: You can use and say a value instead of text like this: engine.say(code value)

Comment: The code is syntactically incorrect. There is no proper indentation.